# Heroku: Firebase can't load credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

**Summary of Problem**

I'm hosting my Node.js server that uses Firebase on Heroku  and when I try to run on Heroku, I get the error below that it can't load my credentials.

It works perfectly when running on my local machine.   I'm using the firebase-admin npm package to configure my firebase connection/instance.

Has anyone encountered this before?  If so, I'd love your help!

**Error from Heroku**

Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.

***Code***

**Firebase Admin Config File**

This is the file I'm using to configure my Firebase admin instance

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: "https://esports-competition-2.firebaseio.com"
}); //this also allows me to use Google OAuth2 refresh token

const db = admin.firestore();

module.exports = db;
```

**Function to save data to firebase**

```
const db = require("../../configs/firebaseConfig");

async function firestorePush(userId, eventType, data) {
  try {
    //read database
    //if userId contains eventType singleEntry then remove from database
    const timeStamp = new Date();
    userId = userId.toString();
    const userDoc = db.collection("pushData").doc(userId);
    const pushData = await userDoc.set(
      {
        event: {
          eventType,
          data,
          timeStamp
        }
      },
      { merge: true }
    );
    console.log("Document set in FireStore", pushData);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("errpr pushing to firebase", err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation on `admin.credential.applicationDefault()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.credential.html#applicationdefault):

> Google Application Default Credentials are available on any Google infrastructure, such as Google App Engine and Google Compute Engine.

Since Heroku is not Google infrastructure, you will have to initialize the Admin SDK with one of the other options shown in the [documentation on initializing the SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk).